# Clear all signatures from Outlook 2011 for Mac

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, office-for-mac, microsoft-outlook-2011

When I try to open the signatures pane, it crashes Outlook 2011.

Is there any way to wipe all of the signatures other than via the signatures menu in Outlook for Mac?

Comment: http://gerardmcgarry.com/blog/where-does-microsoft-outlook-store-signature-files + `DEL`

Comment: Thanks but that's for Windows, I am on a Mac!

Comment: Should have read the tags, sorry.

Comment: I think you'll find the Signatures folder in ~/Documents/Microsoft User Data/Office 2011 Identities/Main Identity/DATA RECORDS/Signatures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting the following file (be sure to take a backup first):

~/Documents/Microsoft User Data/Office 2011 Identities/Main Identity/Signatures